# Webmasters tools "Vendor/channel.php" 404

Tags: cakephp, facebook-apps, google-search-console

I use the Facebook plugin (https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin) for CakePHP 2.x. It is works fine. But the "Webmasters tools" is not founds the 'Vendor/channel.php'.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '281854978625137', // App ID
            channelURL : '../../Vendor/channel.php', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });
```

What is the good channelURL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Filepaths are not urls

Only the webroot of a CakePHP application is web accessible - vendor files cannot be accessed by a url.

A [channel file is required by facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), they also suggest [serving it with long cache headers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/gettingstarted/#channel). The plugin you are using provides the same channel.php file as an example.

To use the channel file copy it into the webroot:

```
cd /path/to/app
cp Plugin/Facebook/Vendor/channel.php webroot/channel.php
```

And then point at it:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '281854978625137', // App ID
        channelURL : 'channel.php', // Channel File
```